# darle formato a un string

Tags: java

Buenas tardes tengo el sig código

```
static String neto = "";
static String tara = "";
static String bruto = "";

    Enviar_datos enviar = new Enviar_datos(conf);
    String bascula = conf.getBascula();
    if (control == 0) {

        conf.CargarConfiguracion();
        bascula = conf.getBascula();

        tara = leido_final;
        System.out.println("tara:" + tara);
        lf1 = Double.parseDouble(leido_final);

    }
    if (control == 1) {

        neto = leido_final;
        System.out.println("neto:" + neto);
        lf2 = Double.parseDouble(leido_final);

    }

    if (control == 2) {
        double brutoi = lf1 + lf2;
        bruto = String.valueOf(brutoi);


        enviar.setPeso_neto(bascula + tara + neto +bruto);
        enviar.converir_datos();
        control = 0;
    }

}
```

mi programa registra las variables con una bascula con el sig formato 0.000
mi pregunta es como puedo rellenar con ceros a la izquierda para darle el siguiente formato 0000000000.000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clase java.text.DecimalFormat, sirve para formatear números.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

```
static String formatoDeseado = "0000000000.000";
static DecimalFormat formateador = new DecimalFormat(formatoDeseado);
```

Para obtener el número formateado:

```
double valor = 123.455;
String valorFormateado = formateador.format(valor);

System.out.println("valor formateado="+valorFormateado);
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Como tal en un dato tipo `Double`no conozco una manera posible de hacerlo. El método que funciona, es pasarlo a un tipo `string`y agregarlos manualmente. Te comparto una función que usé alguna vez para esto:

```
private static String agregarCeros(String string, int largo)
            {
                String ceros = "";

                int cantidad = largo - string.length();

                if (cantidad >= 1)
                {
                    for(int i=0;i<cantidad;i++)
                    {
                        ceros += "0";
                    }

                    return (ceros + string);
                }
                else
                    return string;
            }
```

Lo que hace este método, es que le envías 2 variables, una variable `string`que es el string, y una variable `largo`que es el largo que debería tener tu string, con los 0 agregados a la izquierda.

Si necesitas más información, lo consulté de [Esta pregunta en un sitio externo](https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/foros/Java/679076-RELLENAR-CON-CEROS-A-LA-IZQUIERDA.html)